# Getting Google font to load correctly into an HTML email in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Hello all– I've found several web pages addressing this, but I'm still not having success. I want to load a google font (in this case, Fira Sans) into an html email so that it actually appears in Outlook.

I'm opening the .html file in a browser, where it looks good (but maybe because I have the fonts installed locally), but when I copy it to Outlook it displays as the fallback font, Helvetica.

Here's the code I've cobbled together from various sources, but still no luck:

IN HEAD (tried two things)

1.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,500,500italic" type="text/css">
```

2. 

```html
<style type="text/css">
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,500,500italic);
</style>
```

IN BODY

```html
<td width=300 valign=bottom style="width:225.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica , Arial, sans-serif;">
<p class=MsoNormal><i><span style="font-size:22.0pt; font-family:'Fira Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-weight:500!important; color:#7030A0; font-style:italic;"><font face="'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Joining Together</font></span></i></p>
</td>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Url is wrong. Use any one of the below:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,500&display=swap');
</style>
```

OR

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi there– thanks for the quick response! I'm still having the same issue after trying your new links. Looks ok in browser but defaults to Helvetica in Outlook.

Comment: @FontecillaDesign Try replacing `font-family:'Fira Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;` to just `font-family:'Fira Sans', sans-serif !important;`

Comment: Sorry Manas– even worse. Now it replaced Fira with a serif font.

Answer (score 0):

*The Outlooks* on Windows don't support web fonts (and thus Google fonts). Well, almost… They do read the `@font-face` declaration, but they won't be able to actually load the distant font file. *The Outlooks* (from 2007 to 2016) will fall back to a `serif` font even if you have something else declared in your font stack because they use a different mecanism for fallback fonts (with the properties `mso-generic-font-family` and `mso-font-alt`, set directly in the `@font-face` declaration). See [support for `@font-face` in Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/) and [read more about those specific Outlook properties here](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2019/today-i-learned-about-mso-generic-font-family/).

A common way to tackle this is to hide your font declarations to Outlook by using [conditional comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v%3dvs.85)). Here’s what it’d look like in your case:

```html
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,500,500italic" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```